# internet explorer debugger - how can I stop it?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging

any time here is an error on a webpage I'm visiting the IE debugger starts askig me if I want to debug the page. How can I turn off this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the menu, select Tools > Internet Options.

Go to the Advanced tab.

Scroll down to the Browsing section and check the boxes labelled

- Disable script debugging (Internet
  Explorer)
- Disable script debugging (other)

Comment: Sorry DOK but this does not work with Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: @CodedContainer Well, that is frustrating. In my IE 11 on Windows 8.1, the traditional UI remains unchanged when I access it from either the Tools menu or the gear icon in the upper right. It is still exactly as I described it. As with the other IE (and Windows settings in general) you do still have to click the Apply button as well as OK.

Answer (score 12):

To disable breaking on exceptions with Internet Explorer 11:

1. Open F12 Developer Tools
2. Select the "Debugger" tab
3. Click on the Stop sign icon
4. Select "Never break on exceptions"

Comment: This is the same as my later answer, but without a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

While @don-roby is certainly right about switching browsers, sometimes reality hits hard. Being stuck with IE11 you can disable auto-debugging like so:

1. Developer Tools (`F12`)
2. Debugger (Tab, `CTRL-3`)
3. Change Exception Behavior (ie. the second pause symbol near the center of the toolbar – or simply `CTRL-SHIFT-E`)
4. Select: *Never break on exceptions*.

[image: Screenshot of option Never break on exceptions]

Enjoy the silence.

Comment: This is the same as my earlier answer, but with a screenshot.